# Not able to start AVD in Android studio

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am new to the android world, I am starting Clicking run button to start the AVD but nothing is happening.
If I am clicking Debug option then the AVD i have created does not show in the running device option.

In console this is shown
 "C:\Users\shivamkumar07\Desktop\softwares\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140624\ADT Bundle\sdk\tools\emulator.exe" -avd Nexus_S_API_19 -netspeed full -netdelay none"

Here are few screen shots:

The AVD Which I have created:
[image]

I have used API 21 Android 5.0 and API 19 Android 4.4.2 but both are not working.

I have also set the target device in the Edit Configuration option, Here is the screen shot:

[image]
I am not able to understand how to test my project in the android virtual device? is there some problem with API level or something else? Since I am a beginner I am not familiar with many of the concepts of Android world.

Please help
Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to SDK Manager and check at the very bottom if you have installed "Intel X86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM Installer)". Install it if you don't have it.

Take into account that you'll need to run the downloaded file since it's an installator. If you mouse over the row on SDK Manager you'll be able to see the intallation path.

Comment: Im using Android Studio 2.3.1 and I don't see HAXM in the SDK manager, any solution?

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I had to install Android Emulator from the SDK Download manager.

Answer (score 0):

**I was also getting the same issue. But Finally I have got the solution. You just need to follow the some steps**:-

1. Goto file option in android studio and click on invalid cache and restart
2. Then rebuild the project
3. Then click on one of the option in available devices
4. Finally you will see to start the AVD automatically

Note :- ***Behalf of start the AVD from AVD Manager, start it from run.***